# Solving a Complex Exponential Function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I recently had a quiz that asked a question similar to the following "Solve $3^{1-2x}=4^x\;$". What I am wondering is how you can go from "$x\log_3(4)=1-2x$" to the solution on problems like this. There are other variations on the equation but they all are very similar.

Comment: My edit consisted of formatting only. Go to the Help page and click on "How do I format mathematics here?"

Comment: I saw that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3^{1 - 2x} = 4^x$$
Take the log of any base on both sides. For simplicity, I will just use $\log_{10}$.
$$\log(3^{1 - 2x}) = \log(4^x)$$
$$(1 - 2x)\log(3) = x\log(4)$$
$$\log(3) - x[2\log(3) - \log(4)] = 0$$
$$x = \frac{\log(3)}{2\log(3) - \log(4)}$$
The base I used had no effect on the answer. So, had I used base 3, we would find:
$$x = \frac{1}{2 - \log_{3}(4)}$$

Comment: How were you able to write like that in the answer?

Comment: This site uses mathjax. By surrounding math with $s, you can use it.
Check out: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php